# query wanted to retrieve record from table with known offset in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

I am trying to write a query and fetch the records with some offset.

For Example - If I access the 1st record, along with that I require 5th Record should also be fetched..( Observe the Color codes in the above attachment)

If I access 2nd Record, then add (2+4)= 6th Record should also be fetched.

**One solution** is to retrieve with offset 1 to 5, and fetch the records 1st to 5th record and read only 1st record and last record from the result set..

Problem with this approach if the offset is more, in above case its 5, in real world scenario if the offset can be 1000.. fetching all the 1000+ records and reading 1st and last record woudl defnitely reduce the performance.. So I am looking for fetching directly 1st and nth offset record.

in the attached screen, fetch only 1st and 5th record..

Comment: > directly 1st  means id=1? and how do you get nth?

Comment: Id is not sequential, for just convenience, I made sequential in the attachment, nth number will be provided by user..that will vary everytime

Comment: So what do you mean by 1rst one? and how do calculate 1+nth?

Comment: yes, how to fetch 1+nth record along with 1st record, we cant use first column as those numbers wont be sequential..

Comment: id cannot be trusted -- `DELETE` (and several other operations) will leave a gap and not close up the gap.